# Awk, If test to replace 1 column with 2 columns

Tags: awk

Good day

I have the following data matrix

```
1 1 0 0 1 
2 0 0 1 1 
1 1 0 0 1 
2 1 2 2 0
```

I would like to double the columns according to the following conditions

```
Condition 1   if $i == 0, replace with 1 1 (i.e. in 2 columns)
Condition 2   if  $i == 1, replace with 1 2
Condition 3    if  $i == 2, replace with 2 2
```

So the expected output for the example, would be

```
1 2  1 2  1 1 1 1 1 2 
2 2  1 1  1 1 1 2 1 2 
1 2  1 2  1 1 1 1 1 2 
2 2  1 2  2 2 2 2 1 1
```

I usually use R and Octave matrices but the current matrix in quiet large after a while R get out of memory and it takes long.

Comment: SO supports the `<pre>` tag for preformatted text. Edit your question now and try it. For more information on allowed HTML tags and formatting markup, click the orange question mark on the right of the editor toolbar.

Comment: @outis: It's usually better to use the `010101` button (or indent lines using four spaces) than to use `<pre>`.

Comment: @Dennis: perhaps for the conditions (if they are pseudocode), but the data matrices aren't code. What would be best is `<samp>`, but it isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  map[0] = "1 1"; map[1] = "1 2"; map[2] = "2 2"
  }
{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    printf "%s", (map[$i] (i < NF ? FS : RS))
  }' infile
```

Comment: +1 - very nice! You could do `map[0] = 1 FS 1; `, etc., for maximum flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

If the data matrix only contains 0, 1 or 2, you could use a simple truncation trick:

```
awk '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        printf "%d %d ", 1+ $i/2, 1+ ($i+1)/2 
}' file && echo
```